# Flutter Web Url Route Error While Passing Query Param

Tags: flutter, url, uri, flutter-web

I'm trying to use a url where I get a parameter and assign that parameter to a variable inside the web file.

For example my domain is `example.com` and in this website I need an id for user.
I want to make `example.com/?id=123` and get hold of the `id` query param and assign a variable the param's value 123.

In flutter web device it works but when I host these files it doesn't work on real domain.
And flutter gives me the following error:

```
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/?id=sezen@gmail.com"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be
ignored and "/" will be used instead.
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using that parses the URL? Otherwise how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: hello I posted a new post for code. You are right. Can you look at my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73317848/flutter-web-url-route-doesnt-work-on-real-domain