# Flutter Web Url Route Doesn't Work on Real domain

Tags: flutter, url, uri, flutter-web, query-string

**I'm trying to use a url where I get a parameter and assign that parameter to a variable inside the web file.**

for example my domain is example.com and in this website i need an id for user. I want to make example.com/?id=123 and getting that 123 id and giving a variable 123 value

**In flutter web device It works but when i host this files it doesnt work on real domain. And flutter giving me a**

```
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/?id=sezen@gmail.com"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be
ignored and "/" will be used instead.
```

Here is my code

```
void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      setPathUrlStrategy();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
    
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

String myurl = Uri.base.toString(); //get complete url

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getParams();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getParams();

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'QR Numaratör',
      home: MyHomePage(id: mail),
    );
  }
}

void getParams() {
  var uri = Uri.dataFromString(window.location.href);
  Map<String, String> params = uri.queryParameters;
  var origin = params['id'];
  mail = origin;
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);
  String? id = Uri.base.queryParameters["id"];
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

Comment: In flutter chrome device I am writing http://localhost:30112/?id=sezenhs@gmail.com and it is working. But then i download that files and hosted in my website it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MaterialApp widget, you need to specify onGenerateRoute parameter.
Something like this:

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'QR Numaratör',
  home: MyHomePage(id: mail),
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            switch (kIsWeb? Uri.parse(settings.name).path : settings.name) {
              case'/':
                  Map args = settings.arguments as Map;
                  if(kIsWeb && args == null) {
                     args=Uri.parse(settings.name).queryParameters;
                   }
                  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyHomePage(id: args[id])); 
   }
  });
```

Comment: I just copied it and in Uri.parse(settings.name) part it says String? cant be assigned to String. And I make it Uri.parse(settings.name!) after that when i tried to http://localhost:32267/?id=sezenhs@gmail.com the error show up. Expected value of type Map<dynamic ,dynamic> but got  one type null. Can you just check please. Thank you

Comment: answer edited, check now.

Comment: Now didn't get error but i guess i cant use that id data

in the 
return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyHomePage(id: args[id])); 
part i write 
return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyHomePage(id: args[mail])); 

because i haven't got id variable in MaterialApp does it cause a bug
If I host this to my website will it work

Comment: for your check iam writing my code 
'MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'QR Numaratör',
  home: MyHomePage(id: mail),
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            switch (kIsWeb? Uri.parse(settings.name!).path : settings.name) {
              case'/':
                  Map args = settings.arguments as Map;
                  if(kIsWeb && args == null) {
                     args=Uri.parse(settings.name!).queryParameters;
                   }
                  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyHomePage(id: args[mail])); 
   }
  });'

Comment: In your question, it seemed that you are passing 'id' as parameter. therefore, I put 'id'. you can pass anything depending on the name of your variable. And yes it should work on website too. You can check on website and let me know.

Comment: it is still not working. When i write http://localhost:35950/?id=sezenhs@gmail.com it turns back Expected value of type 'Map<dynamic,dynamic> ' but got one of type Null errorr

Comment: bro you fixed the bug but i was trying to host older files to website. Thank you for your help.